# Laravel Date Mutators Nested Object

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Person Collection

```
    {
      name: 'Jack',
      dateOfBirth: ISODate("1975-12-29T00:00:00.000Z")
      club: {
         name: 'A Club',
         joinedAt: ISODate("2020-10-29T14:12:01.309Z")
      }
    }
```

Person Model

```
protected $dates = ['dateOfBirth'];
```

How can I add the date fields in nested objects to this array?

Comment: please describe your question broadly for better understanding.

Comment: If your are using MongoDB with the laravel extension that allows using eloquent with mongodb then do state so in your question otherwise it's just confusing for most people

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a MongoDB model (which I only speculate because of `ISODate`) and you are using [laravel-mongodb](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb) then you should be able to use the dot-notation for nested dates:

```
protected $dates = [ 'dateOfBirth', 'club.joinedAt' ];
```